# Remove, using jQuery, the first newline of a long text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because of a small system error I am receiving long texts with a newline in the beginning of the texts. Is there a way to remove just this newline? `$.trim()` is removing other white spaces, which is not my intention. I want to remove only the first newline and keep all whitespaces intact.

***For example:***

```
         <------ remove this new line
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

         <------ keep these

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

         <------ keep these

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
```

Comment: Have you tried `trim()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
longString = longString.replace("\n","")
```

this will replace only the first new line.